# How to remove Python 2 from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, 20.04, python3, python-2.7

I've upgraded recently from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. But I can see that Python2 is still the default instead of python 3.8.2.

```bsh
$ python -V

Python 2.7.18rc1

$ python3 -V

Python 3.8.2
```

Is it possible to remove python 2 and replace it with Python 3.8?

**EDIT**:
I have always used the following aliases in my ubuntu 18.04:

```bsh
alias python='python3'
alias pip='pip3'
```

After upgrading, I removed those aliases because I thought python2 should no longer be there but it is still there.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help sorry, but my system automatically removed `python2`, and `python` now reports 3.8.3.  Had you made changes to your python defaults at any time?  (my upgrade path was not LTS to LTS though)

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I was always using an alias to python3 and pip3 from my bashrc file. But I forgot about that before upgrading, but even though ubuntu should be smart enough to rely on absolute paths instead of my bashrc file.

Comment: FYI: Upgrading testing involves no user-changed configs/aliases being setup or used, so for best results you should always change your own modifications back to default before your *release-upgrade* (esp. where related to system used tooling like python!). It is impossible to cater, or test for every possible user-changeable config, however the upgrade path from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS isn't strictly open yet because testing & fixes aren't fully completed (the path opens only **after** the release of 20.04.1)   You could submit a bug report, which may prevent other users from encountering it..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before proceeding make sure that you do not really have packages which depend on Python 2.

Then you need to install [special package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-is-python3&searchon=names) which set aliases for you:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

And optionally remove all trails of Python 2 packages manually by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Comment: That works fine. Just as a note, I am trying to install now a package but it will remove python-is-python3 and install python-is-python2 again.

Comment: @Navaro then you cannot remove Python 2 and its aliases.  The package you are installing "new" has a dependency on Python 2 existing, therefore it *needs* Python 2 to work.  You are stuck without options in this case.

Comment: @ThomasWard: Yes, I am stuck because some packages I use frequently still depend on Python2: VirtualBox, paraviewopenfoam, etc.

Comment: @Navaro then use Python 2 as usual. And do not remove it and its dependents.

Answer (score 11):

As user 'N0rbert' answered, you should install 'python-is-python3' to set aliases.
And then check the packages that depend on python2 before removing them.

As with my experience with ubuntu 20.04 LTS, only python3 was installed, and I installed python2 by mistake. So, it was relatively easy to uninstall python2.

To uninstall, enter following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt remove python2 --simulate
sudo apt remove python2
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

**Break-down** of above commands:

`sudo apt remove python2 --simulate`: perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.

This would print details of what might happen if you remove python2 from the system.
If you are satisfied with the result(outcome) then you may do actual remove by:
`sudo apt remove python2` and then `sudo apt autoremove --purge` to remove the configuration files and the unused packages.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had `python2` still installed after the upgrade from Ubuntu `18.04` to `20.04`, but it was safe to remove based on the `--simulate` output.